# Which jars should I include in the classpath for apache fop

Tags: java, websphere-7, apache-fop

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` with `Apache-FOP` I have included fop.jar in my WEB-INF lib directory in websphere 7.0. I added xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar to my lib and then it throws verify error.

`Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=org/apache/fop/fo/ElementMappingRegistry, method=findFOMaker(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)Lorg/apache/fop/fo/ElementMapping$Maker;, pc=127`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageContext
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:274)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:687)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:510)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    at cat.gis.portal.servicehistory.controllers.EquipmentServiceHistoryDetailsViewController.generatePDF(EquipmentServiceHistoryDetailsViewController.java:281)
    at cat.gis.portal.servicehistory.controllers.EquipmentServiceHistoryDetailsViewController.workOrderDetailsView(EquipmentServiceHistoryDetailsViewController.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleResource(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:825)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:652)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:508)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:508)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    ... 137 more
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match ="services">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="service">
                <fo:region-body></fo:region-body>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="service">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Service Id</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Open Date</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Close Date</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>                                    
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Order Status</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>                                    
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Description</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Repair Cost</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="./service">
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="serviceId" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="openDate" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="closeDate" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>                                
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="orderStatus" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="description" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="repairCost" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Surely this is answered in the documentation?

Comment: @EJP I have found in one of the forum that I need to include `xmlgraphics-commons-1.x.jar` but this one creates `Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent;` error

Comment: I have seen several forums with this problem. Not sure how to get it resolved. I have been stuck here since 2 days. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What is your FOP version? Can you provide some XSL-FO code?

Comment: @RobertG I have FOP 1.1. Please see the update

Comment: It's weird that you don't use any images in the stylesheet, and still the error is about XMLGraphics...

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a jar file is mainly just a zip file with a manifest: Unpack the jar with your favourite unzip tool, have a look inside the *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF* file, and check that everything on the classpath is present. For me (FOP 1.0), the classpath entry is this one:

Class-Path: avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar batik-all-1.7.jar commons-io-1.
 3.1.jar commons-logging-1.0.4.jar fop-hyph.jar serializer-2.7.0.jar s
 ervlet-2.2.jar xalan-2.7.0.jar xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar xml-apis-1.3.04.j
 ar xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar

Answer (score 1):

*...after 5 years...*

I had the same issues and fixed it real quick by iterating all throwed `NoClassDefFoundError`s by searching the package names, e.g. `org.apache.xmlgraphics`, and added all missing `.jars` downloaded from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/).

Maybe, you can use Maven Plugin to avoid the dependency hell and referencing all missing .jars but i didn't try that.

I am using **Apache FOP Version 2.2 from Apr, 2017**. Add all following .jars to your `WEB-INF/lib` and you might be able to process:

- avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
- batik-bridge-1.9.1.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- fop.jar
- org.apache.batik.css-1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
- org.apache.batik.svggen-1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
- org.apache.batik.transcoder-1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
- org.apache.batik.util-1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
- xmlgraphics-commons-2.2.jar